# django link my app's namespaced static directory to my projects static directory

Tags: django

I created an app myapp under my project. Now I created a static directory namespaced by my app's name like this: myapp/static/myapp.
How can I link my app's static directory to my project's static folder (myproject/static)?
Do I create the symlink manually?

Comment: You can run 'python manage.py collectstatic' command. For details read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Comment: Would it hurt If I symlink manually? I tried collectstatic but no luck.